# LOAD DATA en Mysql MacOS

Tags: mysql, macos

No se cargan los datos de mi archivo a la tabla

mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '~/Desktop/hola.txt' INTO TABLE ARTICULOS; Query OK, 0 rows affected, 45 warnings (0,00 sec) Records: 5 Deleted: 0 Skipped: 5 Warnings: 45

Como que encuentra el archivo pero no se cargan los datos (sino encontrara el archivo daría error)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el archivo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí enseño donde se encuentra ubicado el archivo hola.txt en mi desktop:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al checkear los warnings obtengo esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer comando "describe articulos":
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los **ID** al parecer se cargan, intentaste con el separador **TAB** en tu archivo **hola.txt**?

Comment: Sí, cada dato en cada frase está separado con TAB

Comment: Puedes revisar los 45 Warnings y postear uno? Corresponden a cada registro de las 9 columnas.

Comment: me podrías porfa decir como revisar esos warnings?

Comment: Después de ejecutar el comando de cargar los datos, ejecutas: `SHOW WARNINGS\G`, te dejo el link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-warnings.html

Comment: Gracias Eric, he puesto el resultado en la descripción

Comment: Parece ser el problema en la estructura de tu tabla, revisa que el órden de los campos correspondan con el tipo de dato de tu **hola.txt** y el tamaño para evitar el **truncate**

Comment: hola Eric, creo que la estructura está bien, mira he adjuntado un describe articulos en la descripcion

Answer (score 2):

Creo que te falta colocar como están separados los campos

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '~/Desktop/hola.txt' INTO TABLE ARTICULOS
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
```

donde se encuentra el **'\t'** debes indicar el carácter de separación de cada campo

el **'\t'** indica separados por **TAB**

Comment: Hola Juan, he puesto mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '~/Desktop/hola.txt' INTO TABLE ARTICULOS FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';  pero el resultado es el mismo, los warnings están en la descripcion

Comment: Podrias ejecutar el siguiente comando para ver la estructura de tu tabla como indica Eric ```describe ARTICULOS```

Comment: he adjuntado el resultado en la descripcion Juan

Comment: Por lo que puedo ver uno de los problemas es que tienes la columna categoría como not null y en el archivo esta null en la segunda fila ponla para que acepte valores nulos

Comment: por otra parte puede ser que las columnas en el archivo no esta delimitadas por el tab sino por espacios podrias probar con el delimitados de espacio```LOAD DATA INFILE '~/Desktop/hola.txt' INTO TABLE ARTICULOS
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' ```